# Multiple class methods on singleton to avoid subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, afnetworking

I have subclassed AFNetworking's `AFHTTPSessionManager` to create my own http client, I wrote a lot of categories, utilities methods, oauth2, retry login and whatnot.

I have this method to create the `sharedSession`:

```
+ (MTHTTPClient *)sharedSession {
  static MTHTTPClient *sharedSession = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:%@", kABXMyAppProtocol, kABXMyAppHost, kABXMyAppPort]];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    ...
  });

  return sharedSession;
}
```

and everything is fine.

Now I have this requirement to create another client but just with a different `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, for background download/uploads.

I would like to retain all the niceties and categories I built around this http client.

I'm unsure how to proceed, building another class (or singleton subclass, which kinda smells) seems to be not really viable due to the amount of logic I have to duplicate.

Creating another instance method like the one shown above would work? It's my understanding that the purpose of a singleton is to keep only one instance of the class around, so it may be a bad idea or not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s totally cool to create another singleton. There’s nothing magic about a singleton, it’s just an instance you create and re-use. You could have one or a thousand. As long as they’re stored in different `static` variables you’ll be fine.